# filter specific columns in a table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I need to filter in a table specifically some columns and this has to be done with a dropdown, inside the table.
the 3 columns marked in red I want them to be filtered individually, that is to say that each one has a dropdown and can be chosen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr2eF.png)

I show you my code

HTML

```
<div>    
<mat-toolbar  *ngIf="dataSource.length===0" >
    <span>No hay proyectos que mostrar</span>
</mat-toolbar>
<div class="table-container">
    <table *ngIf="dataSource.length>0" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"> 
        <ng-container matColumnDef="client">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Empresa</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.client.companyName ? element.client.companyName:''}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="projectName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Proyecto</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.projectName}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="projecLeader">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Jefe de Proyecto</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.projectLeader.fullName ? element.projectLeader.fullName:'No Asignado'}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="projectPhase">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Fase</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.projectPhase}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="startDate">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Fecha de Inicio</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.startDate |date:'dd/MM/yy'}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="asOfDate">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Fecha de Termino</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.asOfDate |date:'dd/MM/yy'}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>   
    </table>
</div>
```

TS

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RestService } from '../../rest.service';
import { CommonService } from '../../common.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects-underway',
  templateUrl: './projects-underway.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects-underway.component.css']
})
export class ProjectsUnderwayComponent implements OnInit {

  public currentProject: any
  public dataSource: any = [];
  public displayedColumns: string [] = ['client', 'projectName', 'projecLeader',  'projectPhase', 'startDate', 'asOfDate']
  constructor(private rest: RestService, private common: CommonService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.rest.get("/project?projectStatus=Activo")
    .subscribe(result=>{
        this.dataSource = result
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We could make dropdown `Material Select` of options `Material Checkbox` in which we can disable/enable `displayedColumns`. https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumnOptions: any[] = [
    { name: 'position', show: true },
    { name: 'name', show: true },
    { name: 'weight', show: true },
    { name: 'symbol', show: true },
  ];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['symbol', 'position', 'name', 'weight'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

  changeOption(col: any) {
    col.show = !col.show;
    if (this.displayedColumns.includes(col.name)) {
      this.displayedColumns.splice(this.displayedColumns.indexOf(col.name), 1);
    } else {
      this.displayedColumns.push(col.name);
    }
  }
}
```

Html

```html
<h4>Mat-select with checkboxes</h4>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Displayed Columns</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let col of displayedColumnOptions" [value]="col.name">
      <mat-checkbox [checked]="col.show" (change)="changeOption(col)">
        {{col.name}}
      </mat-checkbox>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<h4>The table</h4>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.position}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.weight}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.symbol}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fsemya-ziw56h?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html